# Converting a string to array

Tags: arrays, string, go, terratest

I am working with Go for writing a terratest and I have string `"[[IFN_EYE_HUBW_DEV_AUTO_01] [IFN_EW_HUBW_DEV_AUTO_02]]"`. How can I split this to an array to get `"IFN_EYE_HUBW_DEV_AUTO_01"` and `"IFN_EW_HUBW_DEV_AUTO_02"` as 1st and 2nd element of the array in go?

Comment: Edit the question to show the code that you tried and describe the problems you encountered.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can simply replace all `[` and `]` and then split them with `Fields` as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    inp := "[[IFN_EYE_HUBW_DEV_AUTO_01] [IFN_EW_HUBW_DEV_AUTO_02]]"
    inp = strings.ReplaceAll(inp, "[", "")
    inp = strings.ReplaceAll(inp, "]", "")
    out := strings.Fields(inp)
    fmt.Printf("%v, %v", out[0], out[1])
}
```

Ideally, you should use regex for pattern matching but the above will work just fine for this task.

[Go demo here](https://play.golang.org/p/EPc05t9bQhp)

Note: It will replace all the `[` and `]` brackets so if a string has these brackets then will be replaced too.

Comment: Assumptions are bad. This is very similar to the other answer that used regex for the same. Example: One case it'd fail if you have a string that has "[" or "]" (or both), or some other edge case that OP didn't tell us. I think it'd be better if we clarify everything and then answer.

Comment: I agree and that's why I have explicitly added a note for the scenarios it will not work.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia Thanks..It is working

Answer (score -2):

You may have many solutions for this kind of action but I suggest you to use regexp to solve your issue like this :

```
str := "[[IFN_EYE_HUBW_DEV_AUTO_01] [IFN_EW_HUBW_DEV_AUTO_02]]"
re := regexp.MustCompile(`([A-Z0-9_]+)`)
arrayOfStrings := re.FindAllString(str, -1)
```

Comment: Regular expressions are terribly inefficient, and difficult to read and reason about. There are almost always better solutions. In this case, there are very obvious better solutions.

Comment: Like what ? replacing, splitting, converting, ... are better than Regular expressions ?! How you measure the efficacy of RE ?